# Publish VB Software with MySql Database file (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, installation, publish

I Have a program in VB and i want to publish it into an Executable file including the MySql Database File in Xampp ,

Is there a way to create a Setup file for my Program including The MySql database file without Installing Xampp on another computer that isn't connected to a network?

Comment: What do you mean by "the MySql Database File"? A MySQL setup consists of more that just "a file". And no, you cannot easily "pack" that into an "executable" somehow. A MySQL database management system is a system, not a passive file. You need that system to access the data. Also I do not see how you want to publish an executable via an http server, except to offer it for download. Which does not really make much sense on a network less system.

Comment: If you want a "portable database container", then I suggest you take a look at `sqlite` instead of `MySQL`.

Comment: I want another computer "not connected to a network" to open my software which loads all the Data in the Database file named for example "user_list.sql"     I want to know how to Include the " user_list.sql " with my Software to publish it in a setup file which can then be opened by any users who installed my software.   

Problems:
- I need xampp to start so i can open my Database file , without it i cant load my data in my software

Comment: Sorry, don't get this wrong, but you did not understand how a database server works. You should concentrate on that. There is not file "user_list.sql" that you can somehow hand over to a program and then it is able to use the data stored in that table.

Comment: oh okay so you're saying that i need Xampp to be installed on the computer i want to distribute my software to , My project involves creating a software with Mysql as my backend and Creating a website in which My Software will input data then be inserted into MySql and uploaded to my Website

Comment: No, that all does not really make any sense, sorry. As said above: this reads like you did not et understand how the tools you use actually work. Again: do not get this wrong, you certainly _will_ understand and master this. I just stress this point to make you focus on that.

Comment: Either you want to make a web applciation (based on some xampp package or similar), then there is no use of a "VB program" in this.  Or you have a "VB program" which is meant to intertact with a MySQL database management system. Then there is no use for xampp here. You have to decide which way to go.

Comment: If you decide for the second option mentioned above, a VB program interacting with the database, then that program needs to access the database system directly, that means a system to system communication, so a network. No way around that. You cannot somehow modify some local table and then magically merge that back into a database on another system. That is not how things work.

Comment: Actually i meant that im Gonna program A software in Visual Basic then the data will be Uploaded to a MySql database " Online " which will go to my website

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "which will go to my website"... But certainly it is possible to have some program (be it implemented in VB or whatever language) to interact with a mysql database system and store data. As said: you need to connect to the mysql server via network. You do _not_ copy or otherwise double the database. You always have one central database that all clients connect to. That way all clients share the same database, so the same data. Certainly that can also be different clients, so your program and some "website".

Comment: Maybe it helps you to look at it this way: you need one central database server. That can be your MySQL System which is one of the components of the xampp package, you could also install and use it separate, does not matter. The important thing here is: one central database server which is accessed from all clients at the same time, so from all those "programs" installed on different systems. For that the programs "connect" to that database server, so the open a network connection for which they need to know _where_ that central database server is.